# Is it possible to extract google-services.json from the apk file?

Tags: android, google-api, google-play-services

New to android development. When we distribute the .apk file, can the receiver extract the google-services.json and use our database or authentication database.

I looked 
[I have apk file, Is it possible to get android studio project from apk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54339913/i-have-apk-file-is-it-possible-to-get-android-studio-project-from-apk)
and [Is google-services.json confidential?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36964276/is-google-services-json-confidential)
and [Is it possible to decompile an Android .apk file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3122635/is-it-possible-to-decompile-an-android-apk-file)
but don't directly relate

Comment: can the converted to android resources be extracted from one apk and then used by other project apk?

Comment: no because his SHA-1 will be different and he cannot add his SHA-1 with out your google credentials

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get Google-Service.Json file in decompile apk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42825567/how-to-get-google-service-json-file-in-decompile-apk)

Answer (score 0):

I tried to extract an apk of mine which has google-services.json file and I couldn't find the google-services.json file in extracted folder .

**Edit :**  [Here](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-services-plugin) is more info I found

> The google-services plugin has two main functions:
>
> 1 -  Process the google-services.json file and produce Android resources that can be used in your application's code. See Adding the
> JSON File more information.
>
> 2 -   Add dependencies for basic libraries required for the services you have enabled. This step requires that the apply plugin:
> 'com.google.gms.google-services' line be at the bottom of your
> app/build.gradle file so that no dependency collisions are introduced.
> You can see the result of this step by running ./gradlew
> :app:dependencies.

This means that the google-services.json file will be converted to android resources by google-services plugin during build process .

You can find how google-services.json works over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33083898/6478047)

> can the receiver extract the google-services.json and use our database or authentication database.

Even if the receiver extracts credentials from apk , he cannot access database as the SHA-1 will be different .